# Reset Sprite - Box2d(Cocos2d)

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone, box2d

I have a ball that triggers an action when it collides with a sprite. Then after the action is finished it resets it's position with

```
-(void)removeBall
{
    [self stopAllActions];
    _ballBody->SetTransform(b2Vec2(10, 2), 0);
}
```

But, [self stopAllActions] doesn't stop the action. How can I stop the action?
Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: And what you perform in stopAllActions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using

```
-(void)update:(ccTime)delta
{

}
```

to constaly check if the ballBody has collided with the other body and using the Accelerometer to move the ballBody. So, to reset the position of the ballBody I just replace the scene, which calls the "dealloc" then starts the scene again.

```
[[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene:[HelloWorldLayer scene]];
```

Comment: this is not  the way you suppose to  do

Answer (score 3):

==>You can do the way i have done below

==>  Destroy the the body object and  create new and reset the position were you want to set
this will definitely  work

```
     _world->DestroyBody(_body);
    b2BodyDef  _playerBodyDef;
    _playerBodyDef.type=b2_dynamicBody;
    _playerBodyDef.position.Set(160/PTM_RATIO,240/PTM_RATIO);
    _playerBodyDef.userData=_ball;
    _body=_world->CreateBody(&_playerBodyDef);
    //create the shape for the rounded stick
    b2CircleShape PlayerShape;
    PlayerShape.m_radius = 15.0/PTM_RATIO;  

    //fixtureDef  specifying the shape to circle
    b2FixtureDef _playerShapeDef;
    _playerShapeDef.shape = &PlayerShape;
    _playerShapeDef.density = 1.0f;
    _playerShapeDef.friction = 0.5f;
    _playerShapeDef.restitution = 1.0f;
    _playerShapeDef.filter.groupIndex =k_largeGroup;
    _body->CreateFixture(&_playerShapeDef);
```

Good luck

Comment: Oh ok thanks, so I'm basically just completely removing the ball body then adding it again? I have to go to work, but I'll test it when I get back.

Comment: It didn't work. It's because I am running the action in an "update" method(I run the action after the body collides with another). So, I just replaced the scene ([[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene:[HelloWorldLayer scene]]"

Comment: you need to review your code and put one method in the tick timer method  and call that method from that you can destroy the object and again you can also  reset the position

Comment: @jon can you display the code for Stopallaction method or the code i suggested you

Comment: Did  You refer following Link        http://www.raywenderlich.com/505/how-to-create-a-simple-breakout-game-with-box2d-and-cocos2d-tutorial-part-22

Comment: in this example when sprite  get destroyed you can put code to reset the position  of a body    hope you get some idea:-)

Answer (score 2):

StopAllActions is Cocos2D, not Box2D.  What I do to reuse bodies, sprites, particles etc is set visible=NO and body->SetActive(false).

This is to deactivate the object:

```
CCSprite *sprite = [projectiles objectAtIndex:i];

// Just to continue a loop if the sprite is not visible         
if(sprite.visible == NO) continue;

sprite.visible = NO;

b2Body *body = projectileBodyTracker[i];
body->SetActive(false);
```

This is to reactivate the object:

```
CCSprite *sprite = [projectiles objectAtIndex:i];

sprite.position = moveToPosition;

b2Body *body = projectileBodyTracker[i];
body->SetTransform(moveToPositionVector, rotation);
body->SetActive(true);
```

I have written the additional code off the top of my head so I can't completely be sure it is correct (syntactically), but this is the way I do it.

Comment: I'm using cocos2d to run the required action and I need to reset the sprite so visible = no is not sufficient

Comment: To simplify:  Cocos2D is compatible with Box2D, but Box2D is not entirely compatible with Cocos2D.  If you move sprite with Cocos2D, you are breaking the physics simulation.  If you want to use Box2D for collision detection only (and not simulate any physics at all) then you set your bodies as sensors and use your contact listener to tell you when there has been a collision.

Comment: I'm using Box2d for my game, but I'm also using and action just to animate the sprite when it "falls off" of a platform. Then, I need it to reset.

Comment: Ok what I would do is:  1) Stop all cocos2d actions on the sprite. 2) Set the body inactive.  3)  Move the body and sprite to the "reset location".  4) Set the body active again.  Optional)  You could also set the sprite invisible if you need to for whatever reason.  I personally do that because I constantly reuse my objects, pulling their pointers from arrays.

Comment: I have updated my answer by cutting out some unneeded code and writing some new code to explain moving and reactivating the object.  Hopefully that is more clear.